# Swift - Trim and map the first letter from a Array

Tags: swift, dictionary, indexing, flatmap

I have a List with >2500 client namens and want to create an alphabetical index of the lastNames ( first letter of the lastname ).
When there are white spaces in front of the LastName ( Legacy dataissue, I know, should later get fixed ), they should be removed. If there is no LastName available then it should come up as the last item in the indexArrayro.

result should be
indexArray == ["A","G","I","M","S","Z",""] in uppercase.

This is what I got so far.

```
struct MyObject {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName : String
}

let objectArray : [MyObject?] = [
    MyObject(firstName: "piet", lastName: "mozilla"),
    MyObject(firstName: "jol", lastName: " godzilla"),
    MyObject(firstName: "", lastName: "Anubis"),
    MyObject(firstName: "paul", lastName: ""),
    MyObject(firstName: "", lastName: "Strawberry"),
    nil,
    MyObject(firstName: "jol", lastName: "zwordfish"),
    MyObject(firstName: "jol", lastName: ""),
    MyObject(firstName: "", lastName: "Zwordfish"),
    nil,
    MyObject(firstName: "pot", lastName: "IronFly")
]


extension Array {  
    mutating func rearrange(from: Int, to: Int) {
        insert(remove(at: from), at: to)
    }
}

extension String
{   
    func trim() -> String
    {
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    }
}

let arrayWithNoNils = objectArray.flatMap { $0 } // to remove the 'nil's

let indexedArray = arrayWithNoNils.map({ $0.lastName.prefix(1) }) // get the first character

var indexArr : Array = Set(indexedArray).sorted() as Array // make it unique and sort

if indexArr.count > 0 && indexArr[0] == "" { // move the empty one as last
    let cnt = indexArr.count - 1
    indexArr.rearrange(from: 0, to: cnt)
}
```

Any help on the Trim?
I thought that I could use it in side the

```
arrayWithNoNils.map({ $0.lastName.prefix(1) })
```

something like

```
arrayWithNoNils.map({ $0.lastName.trim.prefix(1) })
```

Any suggestions about this?

As always thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what your expected result and actual result are with the current code.

Comment: Please add the expected output for the sample data you have included. It is very unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Good remark, because Now I remember that I want the result to be uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you your index array by using compactMap to remove nil objects and to trim and get the first character of the last name. This is then cast to a Set to remove duplicates and finally sorted where the closure makes sure "" is sorted last

```
let indexArray = Set(objectArray
    .compactMap { $0?.lastName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).prefix(1).uppercased()})
    .sorted(by: {
        if $0.isEmpty {
            return false
        }
        if $1.isEmpty {
            return true
        }
        return $0 < $1
    })
```

Comment: on the right side of a SwiftUI List a  index ( buttons ) where the user can click on to scroll to the letter of the corresponding lastName with that letter.

Comment: @LordAnubis Ok, I didn't see the code at the bottom of your question

Comment: I think I will use yours and create from that an extension.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

```
let firstLetters = objectArray.map { item -> String in
    guard let item = item else { return "" }
    return String(item.lastName.trim().prefix(1)).uppercased()
}

let indexArray = Array(Dictionary(grouping: firstLetters, by: { $0 }).keys)
    .sorted {
        if $0 == "" { return false }
        if $1 == "" { return true }
        return $0 < $1
    }

print(indexArray) // ["A", "G", "I", "M", "S", "Z", ""]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you looking for?

```
let fixedArray = objectArray.map({ (object) -> MyObject? in
    guard let existedObject = object else { return nil }
    return MyObject(firstName: existedObject.firstName, lastName: existedObject.lastName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it,

the line should become

```
let indexedArray = arrayWithNoNils.map({ (($0.lastName.trim)().uppercased()).prefix(1)
```